# WooCommerce Custom Email template "template_base" not working properly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a plugin that creates custom email templates.

The email templates will be stored on the plugin itself. However, this is not working properly. This is my Email Class

```
 class SV_SplitEmail_New_Order extends WC_Email
{

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {

        $this->id              = 'sv_split_new_order';
        $this->title           = __( 'New Order - Split Orders', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->description     = __( 'New order emails are sent to chosen recipient(s) when a new order is received. Compatible with Split and Plain orders. The default "New Order" email should be disabled.', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->customer_email  = false;
        $this->template_base   = SVTHEMING_PATH.'app/Providers/Order_Splitting/templates/';
        $this->template_html   = 'emails/admin-new-split-order.php';
        $this->placeholders    = array(
            '{order_date}'   => '',
            '{order_number}' => '',
        );

        // Triggers for this email.
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_completed_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_on-hold_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_processing_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_completed_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_on-hold_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );

        // Call parent constructor.
        parent::__construct();


        // Other settings.
        $this->recipient = $this->get_option( 'recipient', get_option( 'admin_email' ) );
    }
```

This shows up correctly on the dashboard.

[image]

However, when the emails get sent out, they are blank.

If I put the email template file on the site's theme folder, this works properly.

However, this is not ideal because on deployment / updates of the plugin, I will always have to update the theme's email templates.

I've made sure to define the `$this->template_base` correctly, and can confirm because the dashboard displays the correct file.

M I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you're still having this issue, but I have been up until recently and found the fix (at least for my problem). Hopefully it'll sort this for you, or help someone else out.

In the `get_content_html()` and `get_content_plain()` functions, you need to pass in the new template_base path. If you modify your functions (or add them if you haven't got them in your class) like this, it should solve it:

```
public function get_content_html() {
            return wc_get_template_html(
                    $this->template_html,
                    array(
                        'order'              => $this->object,
                        'email_heading'      => $this->get_heading(),
                        'additional_content' => $this->get_additional_content(),
                        'sent_to_admin'      => false,
                        'plain_text'         => false,
                        'email'              => $this,
                    ), '', $this->template_base
                );
        }

        public function get_content_plain() {
            return wc_get_template_html(
                    $this->template_plain,
                    array(
                        'order'              => $this->object,
                        'email_heading'      => $this->get_heading(),
                        'additional_content' => $this->get_additional_content(),
                        'sent_to_admin'      => false,
                        'plain_text'         => true,
                        'email'              => $this,
                    ), '', $this->template_base
                );
        }
```

After that it seems to know where to look and my new email class certainly triggered fine.